# Iterative and variable snippet

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Hi there all Im trying to make a snippet in sublime. So that it takes the string and places them into location 1, 2, and so on.

For example this is my string:

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

I want to run snippet on it so it makes it into:

```
console.info('a:', a, 'b:', b, 'c:', c, 'd:', d, 'e:', e);
```

I want it to work for any number of variables, so even for `a, b, c` it will spit out `console.info('a:', a, 'b:', b, 'c:', c)`

I tried all kinds of sublime snippet tutorials but couldnt manage it, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime text has [snippet substitutions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions) but maybe you are not familiar with it syntax. You can use this example snippet content:

```
<content><![CDATA[
console.info(${SELECTION/(\w+)[^\w]*/'\1\:', \1, /g}'_END_');
]]></content>
```

**Explanation**:

We replace every occurence of

```
(\w+)[^\w]*
```

in selection with:

```
'\1\:', \1,
```

- Inside the regex `\w` matches a word character (letter, number or undescore). Those are the characters that variable names use.
- `\w+` matches contiguos `\w`, so it matches a variable name, while `[\w]*` matches non word characters (spaces, commas, separators...)
- In the parénthesis we are capturing a group corresponding the variable name, lets call it first group.
- Then comes the replacemenet. `\1` means output the string that was captured in the first group (variable name). So the entire `'\1\:', \1,` replacement gets replaced for `'variableName:', variableName`
- `\g` modifier means that this is done globally, for every variable name inside the selection (`$SELECTION` variable).

This part adds a problem, as `a, b, c, d` is replaced for `'a:', a, 'b:', b, 'c:', c, 'd:', d,` (look at the problematic extra final comma). Thats why I added a final `'_END_'` token, this is a workarund that maybe you want to replace by an empty string.

Have in mind that we are not making distintion of separators between variable names, so you can use commas, spaces, quotes, etc. as only the variable name will be captured.

So both:

```
age, name, height, weight
age     name,   height       weight
```

Are replaced when the text is selected and the snippet is called (key-binding or command palete) with:

```
console.info('age:', age, 'name:', name, 'height:', height, 'weight:', weight, '_END_');
```